# Cannot set permissions on newly created channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to make my bot able to create private tickets. It can create the channel just fine, but when I try to set the permissions on that channel, it says that `@everyone` is the only role (therefore having default permissions). Also, the console doesn't report any error messages.

To clarify, I can't get the bot to apply permissions to a channel.

```js
const client = new discord.Client();

const config = require("./config.json");

var userTickets = new Map();

client.login(config.token);

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(client.user.username + "has logged in.")
});

client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.author.bot) return;
    if(message.content.toLowerCase() === "?crearticket" && message.channel.id === "729851516667691058") {
    if(userTickets.has(message.author.id) || message.guild.channels.cache.some(channel => 
    channel.name.toLowerCase() === message.author.username + "-ticket")) {
        message.author.send("¡Ya tienes un ticket!");
    }
    else {
        let guild = message.guild;
        message.guild.channels.create(`${message.author.username}-ticket`, {
            type: "text",
            permissionsOverwrites: [
              {
                  id: message.author.id,
                  allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
              },
              {
                  id: message.guild.id,
                  deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]        //This is the part I mentioned.
              },
              {
                  id: "729481759955222538",
                  allow: ["VIEW_CHANNEL"]
              },
            ],
        }).then(ch => {
            console.log("Creado el canal" + ch.name)
            userTickets.set(message.author.id, ch.id);
            console.log(userTickets);
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    }
    else if(message.content.toLowerCase() == "?closeticket"){
        if(userTickets.has(message.author.id))  {
            if(message.channel.id === userTickets.get(message.author.id)) {
                message.channel.delete("Cerrando Ticket")
                .then(channel => {
                    console.log("Eliminado el canal " + channel.name);
                    userTickets.delete(message.author.id);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
            }
        }      
    }
});
```

Comment: Please put your code in your question, not on a 3rd party site.

Comment: @zero298 cant put the code because is very big.

Comment: Then your question may not be a good fit for this site.  We need to see [mre] to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `permissionsOverwrites` to `permissionOverwrites` (you had an extra **s**).
Happy coding!

Comment: It worked perfectly. Thank you!. I'm a simple coder and didn't notice about that. Thank you! x2 @Feixu